# Key value with getimagesize function

Tags: php, arrays, gd

I have seen a code which confuses me a lot. The code is:

```
public static function CreateObject($url){
$url = "temp/".$url;
$imgInfo = getimagesize($url);
switch($imgInfo['mime']){
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $object = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
        //print 'jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $object = imagecreatefrompng($url);
        //print 'png';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $object = imagecreatefromgif($url);
        //print 'gif';
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;

}
return $object;
}
```

Here I just need to know whether in `$imageInfo['mime']` mime is a key or not. I haven’t seen `$imageInfo` declared as an array. And `$imageInfo` is declared as:

```
$url = "temp/".$url;
$imgInfo = getimagesize($url);
```

So I just need to know whether `mime` acts as a key or not.

Comment: `array_key_exists()` as found in the [manual](http://nl1.php.net/array_key_exists).

Comment: why is it declaired like this ..is it an array key there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mime** is absolutely correct key for array returned by [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) function.

According to the manual page:

> Returns an array with up to 7 elements. Not all image types will
> include the **channels** and **bits** elements.
>
> ...
>
> **mime** is the correspondant MIME type of the image.

So **mime** always exists in the result array. Answering your question literaly: yes, **mime** is an array key there.

Comment: but $imgInfo is declaired as $imgInfo = getimagesize($url);.Its not defined as an array ..Is this condition exceptional for getimagesize function ?

Comment: PHP dynamically typecast variables, so whatever `$imgInfo` was before, it will become an array after `getimagesize` function.

Comment: Then what will be thE corresponding value for the mime key ..is that the obtained output ?..i mean the value to the mime key will be the output result of   $object = imagecreatefromjpeg($url); ?

Comment: Obviously, orresponding value for the mime key will be the image's MIME TYPE. Please, read the manual page I linked in my answer.